# How to handle rebuild of graphql query when return to the page (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, flutter-dependencies

I am building ListView from data acquired using graphql api.
I am using flutter_graphql package to handle my request
Here is snippet of builder

```
build(BuildContext context){
return Query(
  options: QueryOptions(
    documentNode: gql(readRepositories),
    variables: {'nRepositories': 50},
  ),
  builder: (QueryResult result, { VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore }) {
    if (result.hasException) {
        return Text(result.exception.toString());
    }
    if (result.loading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    repositories = result.data['viewer']['repositories']['nodes'];

    return ListView.builder(
      controller: repositoriesController,
      itemCount: repositories.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final repository = repositories[index];

        return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.flight_land),
              title: Text(repository['name']),
              onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => RepositoryDetail(repository: repository,))); 
              }
        )
    });
  },
);
}
```

my issue here is that, after user move to detail page. then when user click backButton this build will rebuild and create new request to api.

Notes:

1. There are filters will call this widget and rebuild it
2. There is pagination on scroll

How to handle this scenario?